# GCC-Kernel version Mismatch

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to build a kernel module. But when I am trying to compile the code I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: gcc/kernel version mismatch
+ echo 'gcc version:    4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4'
gcc version:    4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
+ echo 'kernel version: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2'
```

I am using ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The version the of the kernel you are building against does not match the version installed. You need to build against the correct version of the kernel. Use aptitude and match up the headers with the version of the kernel you want to build against and compile with these.

Comment: can you explain a little more on how to use aptitude to make this work? I am actually new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36250528/3182574). It will tell you why it is important to build module on exact running kernel version. Because of which gcc is not allowing you. You can use

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

After installing, edit your makefile to use current version headers, `uname -r` will help you out for this

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```